# Is there a way to prevent the deletion of big query dataset/table if there is an active big query data transfer?

Tags: google-bigquery

Today, I deleted a Big Query Dataset with the tables in it.
Later I found out that there are active big query data transfers that use the deleted tables as targets.

My question is: Is there a way to prevent this by configuration or some other means, to prevent painful mistakes? I was lucky enough to find out that those data transfers did not find any file to transfer since the day they were created.